# Unable to load routes in sf2 using nginx on windows

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I'm trying to set up symfony 2 project using nginx server on windows. `http://localhost/app_dev.php` displays symfony installation page, but entering anything after the url shows 404 error. Even adding slash at the end of that link throws 404 error. So routing simply doesn't work, not even built-in demo.

Configuration:

```
server {
    listen      127.0.0.1:80    default_server;
    #listen     [::1]:80    ipv6only=on;
    server_name  localhost;

    root "c:/wt-nmp/www/admin/web";
    autoindex on;

    allow       127.0.0.1;
    #allow      ::1;
    deny        all;

    location / {
        index     app_dev.php;
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }


    #tools are now served from wt-nmp/include/tools/
    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {                   
        try_files $uri =404; 
        fastcgi_pass    php_farm;
        include     nginx.fastcgi.conf;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404; 
        fastcgi_pass    php_farm;
        include     nginx.fastcgi.conf;
    }


}
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

this solution work with me

```
location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        try_files $uri =404;
    include     nginx.fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass    php_farm;
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include     nginx.fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass    php_farm;
}

location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app_dev.php$is_args$args;
    }
```

When you are in development mode using app_dev.dev here

```
location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app_dev.php$is_args$args;
    }
```

I hope this will help you